# running pytest as a pre-commit hook // no such file or directory issue

Tags: python, pytest, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

in my Python project I use `pytest` as a `pre-commit` hook. Some tests create and delete temporary files, everything works fine when I run `pytest <test directory>`. However, when I run `git commit` and `pre-commit` hook triggers `pytest`, some tests fail because of `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<file name>'`. I have an impression this happens when many files have been changed and are in the staging area (with 1-2 files I do not observe this issue). Here is my `pytest` section from `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pytest-check
        name: pytest-check
        entry: bash -c 'pytest'
        language: system
```

the output looks as follows:

```
pytest-check.............................................................Failed
- hook id: pytest-check
- exit code: 1

tests/utils/test_application.py F                                        [ 91%]
tests/utils/test_image_io.py .FFF.........                               [100%]

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_ ERROR at teardown of test_calling_with_nonexisting_parameter[--non_existing 1337-hm] _

    def teardown_module() -> None:
>       os.remove(OUTPUT_FILE)
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.png'

tests/bdd/step_defs/test_runner_steps.py:98: FileNotFoundError
```

this does not happen when I run pytest from the console.

with `pass_filenames: false` and `always_run: true` the error does not show up any more:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pytest-check
        name: pytest-check
        entry: pytest
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
```

with respect to wrapping things in bash, I'm still doing this for `pylint`:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pylint-check
        name: pylint-check
        entry: bash -c 'find . -name "*.py" | xargs pylint'
        language: system
        types: [python]
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
```

is there any better solution for this? `pylint` does not support recursion of an unlimited depth, thus I need a bash command there.

Thanks!

Best,
Alexey

Answer (score 97):

show your output, we can only guess at the problem otherwise

that said, you probably want to use [`always_run: true`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-always_run) and [`pass_filenames: false`](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-pass_filenames) -- also your `entry` is bogus, no need to wrap things in bash, just call the executable directly.  Putting all that together:

```yaml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pytest-check
        name: pytest-check
        entry: pytest
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
```

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I will post my output below. Btw when is wrapping in bash needed? For example, mypy and pylint do not work properly as pre-commit hooks when calling without a bash wrapper.

Comment: please see my output on this page.

Comment: "do not work" is not a useful bug report, show what you're seeing -- you should never need bash.  don't post as an answer, edit your original question

Answer (score 8):

If you are running various kinds of files through `pre-commit` or using hooks before you commit, you'll need to add another parameter to the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file or it will fail with an exit code of 5 (no tests ran):

```yaml
    - repo: local
      hooks:
      - id: pytest-check
        name: pytest-check
        stages: [commit]
        types: [python]
        entry: pytest
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
```

The addition of the `types` parameter will allow you to pass `pre-commit` even if no tests ran or there are no Python files.